# Getting body bytes from HttpResponse in Netty client

Tags: java, scala, http, netty

I am trying to create HTTP client using netty and everything work, but i have hard time parsing the body. My pipeline looks like this:

```scala
      pipeline.addLast(new HttpClientCodec())
      pipeline.addLast(new HttpContentDecompressor())
      pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1024*10))
      pipeline.addLast(new HttpClientHandler[A](key, metrics))
```

and client handler (written in scala)

```scala
class HttpClientHandler[A: BodyParser](key: AttributeKey[Callback[A]], metrics: Metrics)
    extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler[FullHttpResponse]
    with LazyLogging {

  override def channelRead0(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: FullHttpResponse): Unit = {
    val callback = ctx.channel().attr(key).get()
    if (callback != null) {
      val response = buildResponse(msg)
      callback(response)
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Callback not present in channel context ... this is a bug")
    }
  }

  private def buildResponse(msg: FullHttpResponse): Either[Throwable, Response[A]] = {
    val result = {
      try {
        val parsedBody = BodyParser[A].parse(msg.content().asReadOnly())
        if (msg.status() == HttpResponseStatus.OK) {
          Right(Response.Ok(parsedBody))
        } else {
          Right(Response.Other(msg.status().code(), parsedBody))
        }
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable =>
          Left(e)
      }
    }
    result.fold(metrics.bodyParseFailure, metrics.successfulResponse)
    result
  }

  override def exceptionCaught(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, cause: Throwable): Unit = {
    logger.warn(s"error observed for channel ${ctx.channel()}, closing", cause)
    ctx.channel().attr(key).get().apply(Left(cause))
  }

}
```

The main issue is that `msg.content()` also contains Http data (method, version, headers ...) but im only interested in body. What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's super strange... `msg.content()` is a `ByteBuf` which only should have the payload of the request / response included.

Comment: yes, if i add `println(msg.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8).replace('\n', '~'))`

i get `POST /a/b/c HTTP/1.1~Connection: keep-alive~Host: 0.0.0.0~Accept-Encoding: gzip~Content-Length: 12~~hello dolly!`

Comment: lol i just figured it out ... im testing this against an echo server that repeats the HTTP Request back, that's what got me confused

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was caused by testing this against echo server which repeats the whole http request back, as proven by:

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:3000/a/b/c -v
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> POST /a/b/c HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 19 Dec 2020 09:50:56 GMT
< X-Http-Echo-Server-Id: 9fcf5d57-2ac7-4a92-8aed-775879bf3ac2
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(9.4.24.v20191120)
<
POST /a/b/c HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Host: localhost:3000

* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection 0
```